# jQuery to Javascript code converting

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have not a good Javascript knowledge, but I'm kinda good with jQuery though. I want to change some jQuery code to pure Javascript, but I have no idea how to do it.

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $('#block').one('click', function()
    {
       $(this).val('{L_SEND_CONFIRM}').removeClass('button1');
       $('#replacement').val('{L_BLOCK_CODE}');
    });
});
```

Anyone willing to help me out please?

P.S: Sorry for asking such a dumb question, I really need to learn Javascript myself ASAP.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? And what have you tried already?

Comment: Are you trying to do this as a learning exercise or for a performance reason?  jQuery just extends (and simplifies) JavaScript, but pure JavaScript and jQuery code can be mixed at will.

Comment: I've tried this: 
`var block = document.getElementById('block');
function blacklist_click() {
    block.className = '';
    block.innerHTML = '{LA_SEND_CONFIRM}';
   document.getElementById('replacement').innerHTML = '{LA_BLOCK_CODE}';
};
block.addEventHandler('click', blacklist_click);
block.attachEvent('onclick', blacklist_click);`

It didn't work. I need this Javascript instead of jQuery because of validation by a website, they don't like jQuery because it takes longer to load -.-

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a *rough* equivalent (there are subtleties that if you want to address start getting annoying, thus the need for frameworks in the first place):

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById('block').onclick = function() {
        this.onclick = '';
        this.value = '{L_SEND_CONFIRM}';
        this.className = this.className.replace('button1','');
        document.getElementById('replacement').value = '{L_BLOCK_CODE}';
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the code you provided didn't work, it didn't change the value of my `<input type="text... />`. Any idea what could be wrong?

Comment: @Dugi: I typed getElementBy*ID* instead of getElementBy*Id*. Try it now, should work. http://jsfiddle.net/hxbMg/

Answer (score 0):

`onready` and `onload` are two different beasts.

`onready` fires when the DOM is ready, but graphics may not have been loaded  yet.

`onload` fires when everything needed, including graphics, have finished.

I like this library here to handle the `onready` stuff.  It uses DOM methods for browsers that support it and uses a weird IE hack when it must:

https://github.com/ded/domready